# FileDescriptora Missing Characters

Tags: c#, winforms, com, outlook, clipboard

I am using the code found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) to drag-drop .msg files directly from outlook. The `FileDescriptorA` class is implemented like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public sealed class FILEDESCRIPTORA
{
    public uint dwFlags;
    public Guid clsid;
    public SIZEL sizel;
    public POINTL pointl;
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
}
```

And the code to get the file names is:

```
MemoryStream fgdStream = 
  (MemoryStream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
byte[] fgdBytes = new byte[fgdStream.Length];
fgdStream.Read(fgdBytes, 0, fgdBytes.Length);
fgdStream.Close();

//copy the file group descriptor into unmanaged memory
IntPtr fgdaPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fgdBytes.Length);
Marshal.Copy(fgdBytes, 0, fgdaPtr, fgdBytes.Length);

int numFiles = Marshal.ReadInt32(fgdaPtr);

string[] fileNames = new string[numFiles];

//get the pointer to the first file descriptor
IntPtr fdPtr = (IntPtr)((int)fgdaPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fgdaPointer));

//loop for the number of files acording to the file group descriptor
for(int fdIndex = 0;fdIndex < numfiles;fdIndex++)
{
    //marshal the pointer to the file descriptor as a FILEDESCRIPTORA struct
    object fdObj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(fdPtr, 
                          typeof(NativeMethods.FILEDESCRIPTORA));
    NativeMethods.FILEDESCRIPTORA fd = (NativeMethods.FILEDESCRIPTORA)fdObj;

    //get file name of file descriptor and put in array
    fileNames[fdIndex] = fd.cFileName;

    //move the file descriptor pointer to the next file descriptor
    fdPtr = (IntPtr)((int)fdPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(fd));
}
```

This all works great, except for that the file name coming back is always missing the first couple characters. Does anyone know what would cause that and/or how to fix it?

Comment: On that codeproject page, there is a comment of another person having this issue and a possible solution, did you check that one out?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I did try that, and it didn't help.For me there are 2 missing characters rather than 4.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis never mind, that was still my problem. I had fixed the `FileGroupDescriptorA` block, but not the `FileGroupDescriptorW` block. If you want to put the content of those comments in an answer, I would be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: it feels like stealing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments on [the codeproject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) another person mentions the same problem - in that case the offset of an array item was computed from the start of the structure, not taking into account the first 32/64 bits that contain the number of items in the array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public sealed class FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORA
{
    public uint cItems;
    public FILEDESCRIPTORA[] fgd;
}
```

Comment: In caes that link ever goes dead, the change is making `fgdaPointer` `typeof(uint)` on this line: which appears twice in his code `IntPtr fdPtr = (IntPtr)((int)fgdaPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fgdaPointer));`

Answer (score 0):

```
IntPtr fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileGroupDescriptorWPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptorWPointer) - 4);
```

---

```
fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileDescriptorPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileDescriptor) - 4);
```

`(long)` for 64bit support

`- 4` for taking the first 2 chars   (4 = sizeof(uint))

The logic (not the code) is repeated, so the change must be done twice.

Answer (score 0):

Had to differentiate the code when actually running as a 32 Bit process, since the -4 movement didn't work in this case:

```
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileGroupDescriptorAPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptorAPointer)) - 4;
    }
    else
    {
        fileDescriptorPointer = (IntPtr)((long)fileGroupDescriptorAPointer + Marshal.SizeOf(fileGroupDescriptorAPointer)) ;
    }
```